# proper way to iterate through contents in a directory

Tags: shell-script, ls, wildcards, for, dot-files

I need to iterate through every file inside a directory. One common way I saw was using the for loop that begins with `for file in *; do`. However, I realized that it does not include hidden files (files that begin with a "."). The other obvious way is then do something like

```
for file in `ls -a`; do
```

However, iterating over `ls` is a bad idea because spaces in file names mess everything up. What would be the proper way to iterate through a directory and also get all the hidden files?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just need to create a list of glob matching files, separated by space:

```
for file in .* *; do echo "$file"; done
```

---

**Edit**

The above one can rewrite in different form using brace expansion

```
 for file in {.*,*}; do echo "$file"; done
```

or even shorter: `for file in {.,}*; do echo "$file"; done`

Adding the path for selected files:

```
 for file in /path/{..?,.[!.],}*; do echo "$file"; done
```

Adding path for selected files:

```
 for file in /path/{.,}*; do echo "$file"; done
```

If you want to be sophisticated and remove from the list usually unneeded `.` and `..` just change `{.,}*` to `{..?,.[!.],}*`.

For completeness it is worth to mention that one can also set dotglob to match dot-files with pure `*`.

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

---

In `zsh` one needs additionally set `nullglob` to prevent the error in case of no-matches:

```
setopt nullglob
```

or, alternatively add glob qualifier `N` to the pattern:

```
for file in /path/{.,}*(N); do echo "$file"; done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So if I want to iterate through any directory, I just put the directory name in front of each of the items right? like `for file in dir/.* dir/*; do`

Comment: It's not so easy. `.*` matches `.` and `..` (except in zsh). `*` stays `*` if there is no matching file. `shopt -s gotglob` is only in bash.

Comment: I am getting `zsh: no matches found: .*` when I run the command(s) in this answer. Why would this happen? ls on the directory shows the files.

Comment: @Niyaz that's because `zsh` return error if some pattern no matches. To prevent that run `setopt nullglob` which will turn off this feature globally, or add qualifier `(N)` after the glob star, i.e.: `for file in /path/{.,}*(N); do echo "$file"; done`.